# Shiny, RStudio - how to remove objects created by eventReactive functions

Tags: rstudio, shiny

I'm in Shiny, RStudio. I'm making an app that processes a user input in several steps, each step taking input from the previous step. At each step the user can set several parameters to process the input.

The workflow looks like this:

Step1: upload input from user

```
obj_step1 <- eventReactive(input$actionButton1, {#function to upload input from user})
output$step1 <- renderPlot({#function to display obj_step1})
```

Step2:

```
obj_step2 <- eventReactive(input$actionbutton2, {#function to process obj_step1, taking several user given parameters from the ui with input$})
output$step2 <- renderPlot({#function to display obj_step3})
```

Step3:

```
obj_step3 <- eventReactive(input$actionbutton3, {#function to process obj_step2, taking several user given parameters from the ui with input$})
output$step3 <- renderPlot({#function to display obj_step3})
```

Step4:

```
obj_step4 <- eventReactive(input$actionbutton4, {#function to process obj_step3, taking several user given parameters from the ui with input$})
output$step4 <- renderPlot({#function to display obj_step4})
```

My problem: the user has gone through all the steps and concludes that, to get the best results, he needs to restart the process from step 2, with new parameters. How do I remove all the objects and outputs from the step3-4, to ensure that no mix up takes place?

I've tried `remove(obj_step4())`, but it does not support this type of objects.

Comment: Perhaps `?shinyjs::reset`

Comment: @Carl I've just checked ?shinyjs::reset, and it resets only the values of the shiny input objects.

Comment: `shinyjs::reset()` indeed just reset the value of an input. You may be able to use `shinyjs::hide()` to achieve what you want

Comment: @daattali. I've checked hide and it does not work with output$ objects.

Comment: @CLM `shinyjs::hide()` should absolutely work with output objects, it works on any HTML element. Just give it the id of the uiOutput

Comment: @daattali. You're right, I've tried again with hide and it works. I use a combination of hide() and toggle(), to hide objects from all downstream steps and to show them again when I press the button from the corresponding step.

Comment: @daattali. The only trouble is that I can only put one hide() and one toggle() in an eventReactive at a time, and I have many objects to hide/show, so, I have to write a lot of code... Any suggestions?

Comment: As a general rule I would avoid placing that code inside a reactive (or eventReactive) statement anyway. reactive should only be used to output a value, it should NOT be used for a side effect. If you want to achieve a side effect (such as hiding/showing/etc) then place it inside an observe statement.

Comment: @daattali. Thanks, that's a good advise. In the end, hide/show did not work for me, because my steps take long to process (up to 10 min or more), and if I use show outside the eventReactive (I wanted to place it at the end, after the computations are finished) it shows the again old object until the new data are processed, which can be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

After some days running around in circles, I found the reactiveValues() function from shiny (http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/). It helps to empty the objects from eventReactive functions when  an actionButton of a previous step is pressed. For more details follow the link to the manual pages.